# How to handle an intent which does not have data at first call of an activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities; *Home* is my first activity and *Settings* is my second activity.

The Settings activity is called from the menu of the Home activity, and returns data to home activity through intent.

But first time when I run the android application, the intent will be empty because the second activity is not yet called, so I get exception there (Java null pointer exception).

Can anybody help me out to handle this solution?

**EDIT**: Code

**First Activity:**

```java
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int SETTINGS_ID = 1;
    Intent intn;

    EditText edt1;
    EditText edt2;
    String user, pass;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        intn= new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class);
    }

    private class HttpConnectionRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Code not included
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public void login(View V){

    edt1 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edt2 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    user = edt1.getText().toString();
    pass = edt2.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("Username-->" + user);
    System.out.println("Password-->" + pass);
    String url="";
    url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("serverurl");
    System.out.println("url----->"+url);

    if(((null==user) || ("".equals(user))) && ((null==pass) || ("".equals(pass)) )){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide username and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }
    else if((null==user) || ("".equals(user))){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }
    else if ((null==pass) || ("".equals(pass))){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }

    if ((null==url) || ("".equals(url))) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide the Server url Settings->Server URL->Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }

    HttpConnectionRequest conn= new HttpConnectionRequest();
    conn.execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, SETTINGS_ID, 0, "Settings");
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case SETTINGS_ID:
            //this.finish();
            this.startActivity(intn);
            System.out.println("This Invoked . . .");
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Second activity**

```java
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    EditText edt1;
    Intent intn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        intn = new Intent (this,LoginActivity.class);
    }

    public void save(View v){
        edt1= (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.serverurl);
        String url = edt1.getText().toString();
        intn.putExtra("serverurl",url);
        startActivity(intn);        
    }
}
```

Comment: I am curious on how and where did you get the returned data from the Settings Activity. It seems that the best way to implement this should be using **Activity.startActivityForResult()**.

Comment: The second activity is called when the user selects the option in the menu.

Comment: where do you get the exception exactly? in which event? onCreate() ? onActivityResult() ?

Comment: String url="";     url =getIntent().getExtras().getString("serverurl");  -----> After this statement , I am getting the exception.

Comment: To avoid NullPointerException, it'd better for you to check null before doing any method calling from an object instance. This is always true in all java/android programs. On the other hand, your code will potentially generate infinite loop in Activity stack if users never press "return" button or kill the application, unless you add specific IntentFilter before calling **startActivity()**. A better approach would be using **startActivityForResult()** with the use of **resultCode**. Read more documentations and other post for a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you .. Can you suggest any other options to get the settings page rather than going for an activity.

Comment: @VictorWong Or she could just do a call to finish() after calling startActivity() in the SettingsActivity the intent and she would not have an infinite stack issue. Much easier here to do in here case. The method, startActivityForResult() can be used here, but it is definitely not the only way, and not necessarily the easiest.

Comment: @onit, Agree that **startActivityForResult()** is not the only way, but just one of the better approaches in general.

Comment: @DroidGirl, there is always an option to save and get your setting without going for an activity, this is somehow, from my point of view, depending on the scale and complexity of your settings. For example, you can replace the activity with a simple dialog, but this can be quite complicated if you are not familiar with that.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can do a check for the `resultCode` as below.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#StartingAnActivityForResult

Also, can you identify where exactly you get the exception? (post some code maybe)

**EDIT:**

Ok, I still donT know where you are calling your `login()` method but you can do this check to avoid null exceptions in the line you mentioned:

```
if( getIntent().getExtras() != null)
{
  //do here
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try:

```
if(intent.getExtras() == null) {
   //Do first time stuff here
} else {
  //Do stuff with intent data here
}
```

If you are passing back different intent values every time, you can check if your Bundle object (returned with intent.getExtras()) has certain fields set using this:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras()
if(extras.containsKey("keytocheck")) {
  //Do stuff because extra has been added
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Intent.hasExtra(String name)` to check if an extra with name was passed in the intent.
 For example. you can try like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();    
if(intent.hasExtra(String name)) {      
    // If extra was passed then this block is executed because hasExtra() method would return true on getting extra.    
} else {    
    // If extra was not passed then this block is executed because hasExtra() method would return false on not getting extra.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should post more code, but it will all likely boil down to:

```
onCreate()
{
  ...
  Intent sourceIntent = getIntent();
  if(sourceIntent == null)
  {
      //rare case where setIntent has been called with null
  }else{
    Bundle params = sourceIntent.getExtras();
    if(params != null)
    {
      //read params
    }else{
      //use defaults
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

This is psuedo code, but you'll basically need to check if the intent that is passed to you is null or not. If it is null, you need to have some default values to work with.

Comment: Pretty sure you can never have a null intent. Not to mention this will still crash when you try and read the params if no extras have been added since getExtras() will be null.

Comment: Before you downvote, you should actually know. Here is Diane Hackborn stating that getIntent can return null: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg55782.html .

Comment: So if I explicitly set it to null it will be null. Great response. Ok, so it will never be null in the topic creator's case or in any normal use case. You can never launch an activity with a null intent. Also your code is still unsafe for the other reason's I posted. Definitely deserves a downvote because it is still bad advice.

Comment: I removed my downvote though there is still no reason to check for a null intent.

Answer (score 1):

Use `intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())` to avoid null pointer exception.

```
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!= null) {
                    startActivity(intent);
//Write startActivity code here

                }
```